# Mongoexport - Issue with "\n"

Tags: java, mongodb, mongoexport

I was trying to export the data from Mongo to Oracle. I used to below approach.

```
Step 1 : Export the data to CS file usign mongoExport command. 
Step 2 : Read the data through a java code, do the necessary data transformation. 
Step 3 : Insert the data to Oracle
```

Issue is that, when any of the comment section has a new line character ('\n'), the data is moving to next line and java read fails to process the document.

There is a open bug with 10gen for this, [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8232). Has any one faced issue. Is there is a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many formatting nuances in CSV, there is [no agreed "standard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard) for how to handle embedded newline characters in a CSV field.

A common implementation is [RFC-4180: Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4180), which suggests:

```
6) Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
should be enclosed in double-quotes.

For example:

"aaa","b CRLF
bb","ccc" CRLF
zzz,yyy,xxx
```

This is the format that `mongoexport` is currently using. If you use a CSV parser compliant with RFC-4180 (eg. [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/csv_specification.html) as suggested by @evanchooly) it should handle the quoted newlines as expected.

If you need an alternative to the format used by `mongoexport` or need more flexibility in your output, you can always write your own export script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to parse the csv manually?  If so, take a look at http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ or http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/ and see if they help.

Comment: I believe the issue is more with MongoExport command, For Example, If below is the document in mongo

{"Name":"Srivatsa","Comment":"Some comment /n . Test it "}

When I export it, It is coming something like this.

Srivatsa,SomeComment    ----- here the line breaks                         
----new line starts with 'Test it'. This is causing issue